# d3.js - scaling canvas points to overlay on svg map during zoom

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js

I am rendering a raster map using [d3.geo.tile](http://d3js.org/d3.geo.tile.v0.min.js), like in this example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/9535021) (the raster images don't work on that page, so I cloned it over [here](http://weather-bell.com/test.html)). Unlike this example I have thousands of points to show, so I am rendering them using HTML5 Canvas instead of SVG. I positioned the canvas directly over the map.

The points are rendering correctly, and I am able to pan the map. However, if I zoom in the points are not translated to the proper coordinates.

Here is the function that draws these points:

```
function set_scales() {

    var translate = zoom.sub_regions.translate(), 
        scale = zoom.sub_regions.scale(),
        width = sub_region.get('width'), 
        height = sub_region.get('height');

    var x1 =  -translate[0]+width/2;
    var y1 =  -translate[1]+height/2;
    var x2 =  width + x1;
    var y2 =  height + y1;

    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([x1, x2]).range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([y1, y2]).range([0, height ]);

    draw_canvas();
    function draw_canvas() {
        sub_region.var.context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        var data = sub_region.get('points');
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }
        var i = -1, n = data.length, d, cx, cy;
        var canvas = sub_region.get('context');
        canvas.fillStyle = '#0A00FF';
        canvas.beginPath();
        while (++i < n) {
            d = data[i];
            cx = x(d[0]);
            cy = y(d[1]);
            canvas.moveTo(cx, cy);
            canvas.arc(cx, cy, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        }
        canvas.fill()

    }

}
```

I know that I should be using the `scale` variable in there somehow, but I can't figure out how. The scale at which the points are positioned properly is 4096. I tried making a variable called `zoom_factor` setting it to `4096/scale`, and multiplying the `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` coordinates by it, but that didn't work. Perhaps I didn't do it correctly.

I took some screenshots:

This is before the zoom (points render correctly):

[image: before zoom]

This is after the zoom (points translated to incorrect coordinates):

[image: after zoom]

If you want to see it in all its broken glory go [here](http://weather-bell.com/broken) and click on the United States, then select "Stations."

I could really use some help on this one; been running in circles for days!

Comment: I have a similar point scaling issue with canvas: http://bl.ocks.org/zachcp/0d7d421b6f5eb45d4b72  did you ever figure out your problem?

Comment: @zach I did figure it out, but the problem was not in the code snippet I showed. The problem was mathematical; I was not properly calculating the bounding box of what needs to be transformed. It looks like your problem is a bit different. It is only distorted vertically, and by pan not by zoom.

Comment: @MikeFurlender: Can you share your answer? If you solved the problem you should answer your own question and accept it as the answer. That would help all the ones who come here to check...